# wacom stu-300 , wintab32.dll? Where, how do I start? Cant find wintab32...? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, signature, wacom, electronic-signature

I purchased two Wacom stu-300 signature tabs. I had the ooption of buying the significant SDK/software, but I wanted to interact witht he pads myself. From research I see that I basically need access to wintab32.dll. I cant't find it anywhere? Can someone point me in the right direction?

I am looking to just capture a basic signature. No fancy graphics. Just cap signature. I have tried a few sample apps, but most of them complain about wintab being missing. Wacom seems to explicitly declare that the stu-300 is to be used as part of a compelte solution, and they don;t provide any driver or software for it. The signature pad is installed tho, and shows in devices. Does this tab work / fall into the caterogy of a "tablet" pc functionality?

I would really appreciate some help, maybe a sample app? I would prefer vb.net.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It was last maintained by Wacom.  The DLL is hidden inside their driver installs.  I found it as part of the PenTablet driver version 5.2.5-5a, available at http://www.wacom.com/en/customercare/Drivers.aspx?model=Bamboo&os=

Rather than installing the entire driver, you can extract wintab32.dll from the self-extracting installer.

Answer (score 0):

The stu-300 does not have wintab, Wacom has a set of SDK for the stu tablets, you can request it from https://ssl.wacom.eu/signature.wacom.eu/index.php?page_id=18